# Finding the absolute position of a character in MS Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

Is it possible to find the position of a character in Microsoft Word?

By that I mean, let's say I want to create a macro to join up two full stops with a line. I can draw a line using x and y for the start and end points.

If I type a full stop character, is it possible to get the exact positioning of that character on the page? If so, it would then be possible to join two of these, but I would like to know if it is possible to get the X and Y positions for any character on the page.

Answer (score 0):

This code will show the relative position of the current selection point. Just remember that a "page" in word is a moving target determined by the amount of text, margins, paper size, etc.

```html
Sub getPosition()
    Debug.Print Selection.Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage)
    Debug.Print Selection.Information(wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToPage)
End Sub
```

¨